# multiple lines into a list of variables

Tags: python-textfsm

I'm having difficulty with a show license summary template for cisco.  It's close, but not quite, and this is my first template so any help is appreciated.

The CLI output is

```
Smart Licensing is ENABLED

Registration:
  Status: REGISTERED
  Smart Account: My Company
  Virtual Account: myVa
  Export-Controlled Functionality: ALLOWED
  Last Renewal Attempt: None
  Next Renewal Attempt: Feb 19 19:29:14 2024 CDT

License Authorization:
  Status: OUT OF COMPLIANCE
  Last Communication Attempt: SUCCEEDED
  Next Communication Attempt: Aug 24 07:29:17 2023 CDT

License Usage:
  License                 Entitlement tag               Count Status
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  C9500 Network Advantage (C9500 Network Advantage)         2 AUTHORIZED 
  C9500 48Y4C DNA Adva... (C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage)       2 OUT OF COMPLIANCE
```

My template is

```
Value Filldown SMART_LICENSE_STATE (.*) 
Value Filldown REG_STATUS (\S+)
Value Filldown VIRTUAL_ACCOUNT (.*)
Value LICENSE_AUTH_STATUS (.*)
Value Filldown LAST_COMM_STATUS (.*)
Value LICENSE_TYPE (.*)
Value LICENSE_COUNT (\d+)
Value LICENSE_STATUS (.*)
Value LICENSE_TAG (.*)

Start
  ^Smart Licensing is ${SMART_LICENSE_STATE} 
  ^\s+Status:\s+${REG_STATUS}$$
  ^\s+Virtual\s+Account:\s+${VIRTUAL_ACCOUNT}
  ^\s+Status:\s+${LICENSE_AUTH_STATUS}$$
  ^.*\s+Last Communication Attempt:\s+${LAST_COMM_STATUS}$$
  ^\s-+ -> Continue
  ^\s+${LICENSE_TYPE}.*\(${LICENSE_TAG}\).*${LICENSE_COUNT}\s+${LICENSE_STATUS} -> Record
```

The output though, outputs a 3rd item for some reason.

```
[
    {
        "LAST_COMM_STATUS": "SUCCEEDED",
        "LICENSE_AUTH_STATUS": "OUT OF COMPLIANCE",
        "LICENSE_COUNT": "2",
        "LICENSE_STATUS": "AUTHORIZED ",
        "LICENSE_TAG": "C9500 Network Advantage",
        "LICENSE_TYPE": "C9500 Network Advantage ",
        "REG_STATUS": "REGISTERED",
        "SMART_LICENSE_STATE": "ENABLED",
        "VIRTUAL_ACCOUNT": "myVa"
    },
    {
        "LAST_COMM_STATUS": "SUCCEEDED",
        "LICENSE_AUTH_STATUS": "",
        "LICENSE_COUNT": "2",
        "LICENSE_STATUS": "OUT OF COMPLIANCE ",
        "LICENSE_TAG": "C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage",
        "LICENSE_TYPE": "C9500 48Y4C DNA Adva... ",
        "REG_STATUS": "REGISTERED",
        "SMART_LICENSE_STATE": "ENABLED",
        "VIRTUAL_ACCOUNT": "myVa"
    },
    {
        "LAST_COMM_STATUS": "SUCCEEDED",
        "LICENSE_AUTH_STATUS": "",
        "LICENSE_COUNT": "",
        "LICENSE_STATUS": "",
        "LICENSE_TAG": "",
        "LICENSE_TYPE": "",
        "REG_STATUS": "REGISTERED",
        "SMART_LICENSE_STATE": "ENABLED",
        "VIRTUAL_ACCOUNT": "myVa"
    }
]
```

I've tried a few different things, like using a list for LICENSE to create an array, but I get illegal or duplicate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `Filldown` values. The CLI output likely has a newline at the end, so a new line is started, filldown values are added to the output list, and the other values are left empty because they cannot be matched.

A quick workaround is to identify a value that is always present in the output and make that `Required`. Then when there is no match for this value the empty line is discarded.

For example:

```
Value Filldown SMART_LICENSE_STATE (.*) 
Value Filldown REG_STATUS (\S+)
Value Filldown VIRTUAL_ACCOUNT (.*)
Value LICENSE_AUTH_STATUS (.*)
Value Filldown LAST_COMM_STATUS (.*)
Value Required LICENSE_TYPE (.*)
Value LICENSE_COUNT (\d+)
Value LICENSE_STATUS (.*)
Value LICENSE_TAG (.*)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was way too easy!

Do you have any thoughts on how to make it one item with an array of the licenses?

Comment: @ntwrkguy I'm not really sure what you mean with "one item with an array of the licenses", it would be better to ask a new question about this. As a guess, it might be easier to post-process the output in Python rather than trying to do it in the FSM template. You can use your current output with a list of dictionaries for that, or use `ParseText()` for a simple nested list.

Comment: I guess what I mean would be all the licenses in a list

```{
        "LAST_COMM_STATUS": "SUCCEEDED",
        "LICENSE_AUTH_STATUS": "",
        "LICENSE_COUNT": "2",
        "LICENSE_STATUS": "OUT OF COMPLIANCE ",
        "LICENSE_TAG": [{ "LICENSE" :"C9500 48Y4C DNA Advantage",         "LICENSE_TYPE": "C9500 48Y4C DNA Adva... ",}, {"LICENSE": "NEXT LICENSE LINE"} 

        "REG_STATUS": "REGISTERED",
        "SMART_LICENSE_STATE": "ENABLED",
        "VIRTUAL_ACCOUNT": "myVa"
    },```